# How to export full or partial content of an org file on demand

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I wrote some notes on some papers I've read in an Emacs org file so that I can recall what's in those papers by simply walk through my notes. However, for some reasons, I need to print only parts of the notes (I export org file to LaTeX, and it print the pdf file). Of course I can make a replication of that file and delete all the contents I don't need, but I want to know if it is possible to keep writing notes on that file while still being able to print only parts of them in the future. These parts are not continuous. What I imagine is like an `#ifndef` in C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org-mode` supports selective export through [tags](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tags.html). If you have one or more subtrees in your `.org` file that are tagged with `:export:`, the `org-mode` exporter will include only those in the exported file. To add tags to a subtree, press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> anywhere on its headline, enter one or more tags (separated by `:`) and press <kbd>RET</kbd>.

For any file that has a number of subtrees tagged for export you can instruct `org-mode` to export *everything* by adding the following [in-buffer setting](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) to the top of your `.org` file:

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: export
```

You do not have to remove the `:export:` tags.

Comment: Thanks! Though I hoped to export parts in a single headline, this is helpful for I can actually add more headlines...

Answer (score 1):

You can also highlight (Mark Set) what you want to export, C-c C-e C-s then how you want to export (html, LaTeX, etc.